# UseEffect to update navbar when user is logged in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I'm working on a navbar that changes whenever it detects there is a user in local storage using useState and useEffect. Here's my logic:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState("")
  

  function fetchData(){
    const item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name'))
    if(item) {
      setUser(item)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      fetchData()
});

return({user? (<LoggedIn />) : (<ClientBar />})
```

The code essentially begins with no user, and in the `fetchData()` function it checks whether a user exists in local storage and sets the user based on what's been found in local storage. I can tell the logic works because when I refresh it, it changes from `<ClientBar>` to `<LoggedIn>`. However, the problem is it doesn't work upon login - rather, it requires a refresh to update. Is there a way to make it update immediately upon login?

Comment: if you want to run this code on mount you have to define empty array in useEffect dependecy `useEffect(() => {
      fetchData()
},[]);`

Comment: @abhipatil yeah I did - doesn't make a difference, it doesn't run in real time and requires a refresh to re-render.

Comment: are you trying that if you delete the name property from local storage it should immediatly render and get to login? if yes . then you need to add your custom event listener to check for changes. if no? then explain what you want to perform

Comment: @abhipatil I've tried deleting the name from localstorage and it requires a refresh to redirect back to login. I want the navbar to re-render as soon as a name is added to local storage as the <LoggedIn /> component, rather than the default <ClientBar /> component. The only way I've found to do this is setting up a global state, but I wanted to know if I could get by without it.

Answer (score 1):

As Abhi Patil stated, you need to check localStorage changes. It has nothing to do with `useEffect` as it is only triggered when the component is mounted.

You need to wrap `fetchData()` inside `storage` event listener like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
 window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
  const item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name'))
    if(item) {
      setUser(item)
    }
 })
})
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer - it didn't actually work when I logged in and the `name` and `authToken` fields were set in local storage, but it did update when I deleted the `authToken`? Obviously this isn't sustainable, but it does show me that this code does indeed work when storage changes. Do you have any idea how to make it so that it detects when something is added to storage and updates that way? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your `useEffect` should be:

```
useEffect(() => {
      fetchData()
}, [user])
```

So when `user` changes it will check each time. Because you're fetching `localstorage` I'd also encourage you to add a loading component while that's being done.

Checking `localstorage` Should also be using async/await:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    const item = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name'))
    if(item) setUser(item)
  }
```

While this it's waiting for the check you should render a loading with another `useState`.

Comment: Hi, I tried this already - it works on refresh but not immediately when the user's name is added to local storage. Also, I'm not sure what a loading component is, but I'd love to learn more about it!

Comment: Because `fetchData` should incorporate async await. You would have to build a loading component..

Comment: Hey @darthvader, I tried your solution and I get the same issue despite using async await. It works when I remove a `dummy` item from localstorage, so is there a way I can do that upon loading the the redirected page so that it looks synchronized?

Comment: build a codesandbox with what you're trying to do and I will try to help.

Comment: Hey man, I fixed it. Thank you though, I appreciate it.